# Unicorns are the best use of VC

Tags: discussion, fun, unicorns, business-model

Now we know why Jeff and Joel were raising venture capital.  It's been used to purchase the entire world's supply of unicorns in order to make the SO family in the world leader in unicornified Q/A sites.  Most awesome use of VC ever!

Comment: Unicorns should sooooo be one of the acceptable meta tags.

Comment: Hostile takeover of everything pointy?

Comment: @Jon - are you implying that Jeff is a pointy-haired boss? :)

Answer (score 4):

I, For One, Welcome My Pointy Head Overlords.

... oh, wait, nothing changed ...